# Resize scrollView programmatically according to contenView size [Swift]

Tags: swift, view, uiscrollview

In my app I'm try to creating an auto resizing scroll view according to the content, here's a simplified version of what I mean.
I know that I should use contentView, but with this is doesn't work!

```
    view.addSubview(mainScrollView)
    mainScrollView.addSubview(contentView)

    mainScrollView.anchorFor(superview: view) // .zero to all edges of view

    let view1 = UIView(frame: view.frame)
    view1.backgroundColor = .red

    let view2 = UIView(frame: view.frame)
    view2.backgroundColor = .brown
    view2.frame.origin.y = view1.frame.height

    mainScrollView.contentSize.height = 2 * view.frame.height
```

Now if I don't specify the contentSize only the red view appear.
I've also tried this way:

```
    let contentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.backgroundColor = .black

    contentView.fillSuperview() // .zero to scrollview edges, but it doesn't work
        .
        .
        .
    contentView.addSubviews(view1,view2)
```

How can I make a scoll view thant resize himself according to contentView size that can change, for example by click a button "expand", all programmatically no storyboard.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding all `subview`, You need to calculate `contentSize` using the below code.

```
let contentRect: CGRect = scrollView.subviews.reduce(into: .zero) { rect, view in
    rect = rect.union(view.frame)
}
scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
```

## Note:

If your `subview` add and remove dynamically then do not forgot to call it.

Comment: It doesn't work, Do I have to let the constraints for contentView?

Comment: No, We can do it by auto-resizing